# Compiling python pyo files

Tags: python-3.x, compilation

I have an old c++/python project that includes a python zip file "python27.zip". This zip file contains pyo optimized files.
I am trying to update python from 2.7 to the latest 3.7.1 (also updated the *.so lib file)
I did the next steps:

```
./configure --enable-shared --prefix=~/python-3.7.1/dist
make
sudo make install
```

I see that I have `~/python-3.7.1/dist/lib/python3.7` and it's structure is close to that I have in my old 2.7 zip. 
Next I try to compile all the folder into pyo like:

```
python3.7 -O -m compileall .
```

It tells me that it requires Lib and Include (the headers) so I copied those 2 folders in that location too.
Doing  `python3.7 -O -m compileall .` again inside `dist/lib/python3.7` shows me

```
Listing './Lib/site-packages'...
Listing './Lib/sqlite3'...
....
```

and some errors like:

```
Compiling './Lib/test/badsyntax_future10.py'...
***   File "./Lib/test/badsyntax_future10.py", line 3
    from __future__ import print_function
                                        ^
SyntaxError: from __future__ imports must occur at the beginning of the file
```

I don't see any pyo's inside. Also if I try to do the same against 1 file, like `python3.7 -O token.py` (no errors) and also no pyo inside.
Don't judge me strict, I agree that I can be wrong in understanding this compilation process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create my own tool since I had not found anything suitable for the compilation of all python modules into one location/archive.

This [PY_COMPILE_HELPER](https://github.com/Igor-ua/py-compile-helper) is available on the github. It was tested only from ubuntu.

With this module you can:

- Set input and output folder for the compilation
- Output source will have the same structure as the input source
- Set optimization level for binary files
- Skip or include test modules
- Compress compiled files into one archive
- Clean previously compiled files from the cache

Usage example:

```
$ ./py_compile_helper.py ./Python-3.7.1/Lib ./out -z -c -o2
```